# Stormcrawler - Run -- remote on localhost

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I have setup all the SC steps and I am able to index and crawl, but when I try to run the below command as `--remote`, it fails with an error.

```
storm jar target/search-search1.0.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --remote es-crawler.flux
```

The error that I get is:

> Must submit topologies using the 'storm' client... 
>   [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukPJn.png)

Which is why the storm UI Topology Summary does not get populated.
[Storm-UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbd0a.png)

Can you please give some pointers and things that I can look at? I have checked into my local Storm Setup, and it seems fine.

Comment: Please post your Storm version and OS. The storm jar script is supposed to set the "storm.jar" system property, and it looks like that's not happening in your case for some reason.

Comment: I am using apache-storm-1.1.1 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use the `storm.py` script instead of `storm.cmd`? As I mentioned in the comment you are missing the "storm.jar" system property for some reason, my best guess would be that the `storm.cmd` script is failing to set it for some reason.

Edit: You probably need to upgrade to Storm 1.1.2 at minimum to try this, since the `storm.py` script doesn't work on Windows in 1.1.1. That'll also add a powershell script to your storm/bin directory you can use instead of the `storm.cmd` script.